# rspecで、factorybotで一式createするような便利メソッドを作成してファイル間で共通化したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

以下のように、user３名とその関連データを一式作りたいとします。

```rb
before do
  user1 = create(:user)
  create(:profile, user_id: user1.id)
  create(:image, user_id: user1.id)
  create(:birthday, user_id: user1.id)

  user2 = create(:user)
  create(:profile, user_id: user2.id)
  create(:image, user_id: user2.id)
  create(:birthday, user_id: user2.id)

  user3 = create(:user)
  create(:profile, user_id: user3.id)
  create(:image, user_id: user3.id)
  create(:birthday, user_id: user3.id)

  create(:article, user_id: user1.id)
  create(:article, user_id: user2.id)
  create(:article, user_id: user3.id)
end
```

上記だと冗長なので以下のようにしたいと思いました。

```rb
def create_user
  user = create(:user)
  create(:profile, user_id: user.id)
  create(:image, user_id: user.id)
  create(:birthday, user_id: user.id)
end

before do
  user1 = create_user
  user2 = create_user
  user3 = create_user

  create(:article, user_id: user1.id)
  create(:article, user_id: user2.id)
  create(:article, user_id: user3.id)
end
```

この`create_user`メソッドを別のファイルのspecとも共通化したいと思いました。
rspecは`supports`というディレクトリに共通処理を書くっぽいんですが、modelでよく使われる`concerns`を使って共通化してもよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

まず、関連するレコードを同時に作成するのは以下のように書くこともできます。

```
create(:user) do |user|
  create(:profile, user_id: user.id)
  create(:image, user_id: user.id)
  create(:birthday, user_id: user.id)
end
```

あるいは、これらのアソシエーションが必ず必要なのであれば最初から `user` factory の方に定義しておけば `create(:user)` だけでアソシエーションも作られます。オプショナルだがよく使うのであれば、`trait` として定義しておくとコード量が減ります。

次に、`user` factory を使ってモックを複数 `create` する場合、`create_list` という書き方が使えます。

```
create_list(:user, 3)
```

アソシエーションについて factory 側で定義したのであれば上のようなコードだけで済みますし、ブロックを使うことにしたのであれば `create_list` もブロックを受け付けるので似たような形で記述できます。

これらのテクニックを使うと、メソッドを定義するまでもなくコード量が減るかなと思います。

Factorybot の便利な機能は GETTING_STARTED によくまとまっているので一読しておくと便利です。 https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: ありがとうございます！！
実は今回省略したんですが、create_userには引数をとれるようにしたいんですよね。引数をとってそれを関連テーブル作成時に使う感じですね。
create_user(name: "foo", date: "4/1")みたいな感じですね。trait引数とれなかったはずなので、この要件だと厳しそうです。引数とる場合だとやはりメソッド定義しかなさそうでしょうか？

Comment: trait を使う場合でも、transient をメソッド引数のように使えば良い感じになる場合が多いかと思います https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes

Comment: ありがとうございます！！